# How to download file which is a response in binary from the server, using cURL with OOP?

Tags: php, json, oop, curl

Been strugling for some time now and can't figure out what am i missing...

I wrote a simple class to use cURL as OOP. It works well with all the API requests, except one, downloading the file.

Requests are sent to the server in JSON format using POST method. Response also comes as JSON. The download API is the only one, that is not responding in JSON, but sending the file directly in binary. This one doesn't seem to work with my little class.

Could you please take a look at my code below and advise? Would be very much appreciated!

curlClass.php -> Class file containing cURL methods.

```
<?php

class curlClass {
    private $_cookie_jar;

    public function login($email, $password, $url){
        $ch = curl_init($url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$email:$password");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $this->_cookie_jar = tempnam('folder','cookie_');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->_cookie_jar);
        $_SESSION['cookieFile'] = $this->_cookie_jar;

        $page = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        return strlen($page);
    }

    public function postApi($post_data, $cookie_j, $url){

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_j);
        $page = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $json = json_decode($page);

        return json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }

    public function downloadFile($post_data, $cookie_j, $url){

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_j);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        // Then, after your curl_exec call:
        $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
        $header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
        $body = substr($response, $header_size);

        curl_close($ch);

        return json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); 
        exit();
    }
}

?>
```

index.php -> This is where i call the class and its functions.

```
<?php
    require_once 'core/init.php';

    $curl = new Curl();

    if($curl->login('username', 'password', 'https://example.com/api' > 0){

        $data = array('someRequest', 24);

        $data_string = json_encode($data);

        echo $curl->downloadFile($data_string, $_SESSION['cookieFile'], 'https://example.com/api');

    }
?>
```

However, if i use the download.php as an individual file, it works as expected. The problem is that i need to pass the login credentials to it. Only if i could use the class, then i can login once and re-use the cookies for further queries..

download.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'core/init.php';

    $login = 'username';
    $password = 'password';
    $url = 'https://example.com/api';
    $data = array("someRequest", 25);

    $data_string = json_encode($data);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


    $file = curl_exec($ch);

    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $header = substr($file, 0, $header_size);
    $body = substr($file, $header_size);
    $header_items = explode("\n", $header);

    curl_close($ch);

    echo '<pre>'.print_r($file, true).'</pre>';
    exit();
?>
```

Thank you in advance for your advices!

Comment: Inside `downloadFile`: `return json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); `  Probably shouldn't be there if it's not JSON like you said?  Presumably you're just encoding a single string.  Just return the contents?

Comment: @drew010 that was it! I've even created separate method for the download, but did not realise i am formatting it to json. Write it as Answer, as that's the solution. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Glad that was it!  I posted it as an answer so you can accept and increase your reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `downloadFile()` function, you have `return json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` which seems incorrect.

This encodes the response into a string, which would then need to be decoded again if you want to use it.

It seems the most appropriate thing to do is just return a string (the content) from this function instead of a JSON string.  `return $response;` would suffice.